# Tag Helper not populating form values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a simple MVC Core 2.1 form I'm trying to build, but for some reason, the tag helpers are not being populated in the browser.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit()
    {
        int websiteID = 0;

        websiteID = GetSessionStateInt("WebsiteId");

        if (websiteID == 0)
        {
            // (something went wrong)
            return NotFound();
        }
        else
        {
            // Get the home/mission statement details
            int WebsitesHomeId = 1;

            var tempId = _db.WebsitesHomeID.FromSql("EXEC [dbo].[GetWebsitesHomeID] @iWebsiteID", new SqlParameter("@iWebsiteID", websiteID));

            var WebsitesHome = await _db.WebsitesHome.FindAsync(WebsitesHomeId);
            if (WebsitesHome == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(WebsitesHome);
        }

    }
```

Here's the CSHTML...

```
    @model PHAwebsites.Models.WebsitesHome
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home/Mission Statement";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}

<h2 class="text-info">Edit Home Info and Mission Statement</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <form method="post" asp-action="Edit">
            <div class="p-4 border rounded row">
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" />
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-4">
                            <label asp-for="MissionStatement"></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-8">
                            <input type="text" asp-for="MissionStatement" class="form-control" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Any idea on what I may be missing here? I have almost identical code in another project that works fine. I've tried just about everything I can think of and I've been searching all morning (about 3 hours now) for a solution, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be that your _ViewImports.cshtml file is missing `@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your _ViewImport.cshtml make sure you have this line

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Comment: Thanks Tony, that was it. I also have to give credit to Antti Koskela. I found the answer in his blog and it worked. He had the same problem. For me, the @addTagHelper was in the _ViewImports.html file, in under the main "Views" folder, but the CSHTML file was in a separate "Areas" folder, so there was no _ViewImports.html fle. Adding that to the Area's views folder did the trick.